# Why does the base64_encode function throws an error on only one of my servers?

Tags: php

I use php built-in function called "base64_encode" to send encoded data to my application. On one of my servers it works flawlessly. 
On my second server it throws:

> "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 12298126926392233336 bytes)".

Both servers run on Ubuntu 18.04.2 (running MySQL, PHP 7.3.3 and Apache 2).

```py
$credentials = array("Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode($GLOBALS['login'].":".$GLOBALS['password']));
```

Comment: something is wrong in your other server. For example it runs with different data and soem data are malformed or sth like that. The error you get about memory allocation means either the data are very large (is this normal?) or maybe malformed

Comment: @NikosM.Thanks for Your answer. Well, I tried swapping the variables with fixed data ($GLOBALS['login'] and $GLOBALS['password'] with according credentials), but it still didn't help. To be honset, I spent over 2 hours with this problem and I still can't get the answer.

Comment: maybe the memory error corresponds to other part of code, are you sure it is with `base64_encode` function?

Comment: @NikosM. Yes, the error message specifies the line of code where the error occures. In my case it's the aforementioned line. Hmm, actually it might also be the "array" function when I think about it now.